# Ajax Modal to PHP with id=?

Tags: java, php, mysql, ajax, modal-dialog

This code is working fine but what i need is to make it work with ID values from Mysql data base we have.

```
    <a type='button' href='javascript:;' onclick='editModal()' class='btn btn green btn-outline btn-xs margin-top-10'> <i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Answer</a>

<script>    
        // Show Edit modal
        function editModal() {
            $.ajaxModal('#editModal','support_answer.php?id=1005');
        }
</script>
```

We are using a simple mysql connection based in php, this work fine

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM support_tickets WHERE id = ?";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

  while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo "any data i want";
```

We get the information with this:  `$row1['id']`
Lets say   `$row1['id']  =  1005`

But doing the rows we want:

```
 $.ajaxModal('#editModal','support_answer.php?id=1005');
```

be like

```
 $.ajaxModal('#editModal','support_answer.php?id=?');
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a type='button' href='javascript:;' onclick='editModal(1005)' class='btn btn green btn-outline btn-xs margin-top-10'> <i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Answer</a>

<script>    
        // Show Edit modal
        function editModal(id) {
            $.ajaxModal('#editModal','support_answer.php?id='+id);
        }
</script>
```